# conditional validation newform.aspx

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

Using Share Point Designer 2010.

I want to conduct client side  validation (jquery) but I don’t know how to run my code before the form gets submitted.  The reason for this is my form has jquery that hides/shows certain fields . So different fields are mandatory depending on client side selection.

Originally I tried to do this with the built in server sided validation but they cannot handle conditional validation, I don’t think.

Comment: Another option is to use infopath to create the form - you can write logic for validation in the infopath form.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010? From your use of Designer 2010, I would assume so, but it would be good to be certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this bit of JavaScript may help, assuming you have jQuery loaded as well:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
  return formIsValid(); //formIsValid returns false then the form is not submitted, if true then the submission continues
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript

```
function PreSaveAction() {
    if(....)
    {
        alert("write something");
        return false;
    }

    return true; 
}
```

I don't know if this helps.